# Can't resolve all parameters for ReportComponent: while using ILocationService

Tags: angular

I want to redirect to the .aspx path when clicking upon the button. 
Here my code snippet

**report.component.ts**

```
import * as angular from "angular";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-report',
  templateUrl: './report.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./report.component.css']
})
export class ReportComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private $location:angular.ILocationService) {  
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  viewReport(){    
    this.$location.path("/frmCommIntegrationReport.aspx");
    }
}
```

**report.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="viewReport()">View</button>
</div>
```

But I am facing the issue in console while referring **ILocationService** in the constructor.

[Console Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CN3Uo.png)

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `angular.ILocationService` is an interface and interface is removed during compilation. The error says `ReportComponent: (?)` - the question mark is that Angular doesn't know the type. You need to find the implementation of this interface.

@edit
Btw. this is a strange way of importing things in Angular. Normally it goes like this:

```js
import {Location} from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
class Component {
    constructor(private location: Location) {}
}
```

Comment: Hi @Humberd, Thanks for your support. I tried this way but I can't refer the path here. Here the `path()` returning boolean type.

Answer (score 0):

Import router from library

```
import { Router} from '@angular/router';
```

Then inject it

```
constructor(private router: Route) { }
```

and here is how you can navigate to page

```
viewReport(){    
         this.router.navigate(['/frmCommIntegrationReport.aspx']);  
}
```

Comment: Hi @gaurav_thakkar, the URL link should not change. My requirement is to refer ASPX page in the HTML. So am using the location path.